Proving the Conditional Expectation of a Uniformly Distributed Random Variable Given the Sum of Two i.i.d. Uniform Random Variables
Consider two independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables (X) and (Y), each having a uniform distribution over the interval ([0, 1]). Define a new random variable (Z) as the sum of (X) and (Y), that is, (Z = X + Y). Prove that the conditional expectation of (X) given (Z), denoted as (E(X | Z)), is equal to (Z/2).

Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

$E(X|Z)=E(Y|Z)$ and $E(X|Z)+E(Y|Z)=E(X+Y|Z)=E(Z|Z)=Z$ implies the  result.
